# how to explicitly include a header file from Platform SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, environment-variables

My win32 application already has a file named windows.h as part of it's source and due to the order specified in the "Include Directories", this windows.h gets precedence over the original windows.h (Platform SDK).
But, at some places, I'm required to include the original windows.h.
I can do this by explicitly specifying the path like so:

```
#include <FULL PATH OF windows.h>
```

But, I don't want to do it this way since then the source will become dependent on the location of Visual Studio (2012) installation.

I looked up ways to do this and one way was to use environment variable $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) that would expand to the correct location. Like so:

First, I defined a preprocessor macro:

SDK_INC=$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)

Then I included windows.h like so:

```
#include <SDK_INC\windows.h>
```

But this doesn't work perhaps because macro substitution takes place in a preprocessing phase AFTER the header file replacement.

Any suggestions on how I should go about this?

Comment: Maybe it easier just to rename own windows.h ?

Comment: It is a good practice to give C++ headers `.hpp` extension to separate them from C headers and to organize includes folder structure to match namespace structure (like in boost) so such clashes will never occur.

Comment: or put your windows.h in a separate folder which is not directly in your include path. So you can say: `#include "my_subdir/windows.h"`

Comment: @FlorianM. this is not possible as the custom windows.h is included in numerous files and will therfore require modifying all those file.

Comment: Are you unable to change the files? Or do you mind the effort of changing the files?

Comment: @FlorianM. yes the effort to change all the #include statements in all the files will be enormous.

Comment: Well, sometimes you need to spend the effort if it is the right thing to do. And I agree with @VTT that organizing header files according to their namespaces is a clean way to avoid such conflicts. A good IDE helps you renaming / moving files and change all include statements according to the new structure.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <windows.h> <- SDK
#include "windows.h" <- you own file
```

Comment: this doesn't work as I told that due the build order specified in the "Include Directories",  the custom directory holding the custom windows.h gets precedence and hence that gets picked.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.